# VS Code collapses folder in Explorer View when it gets focus for multi-root workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code Explorer has some expanded folders, for example:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── fizz
│   └── buzz
└── bar
```

Whenever I <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> or switch to another window, and then switch back to VS Code, it collapses my folders

```
.
├── foo
└── bar
```

It has only started doing this today, and is getting increasingly annoying, especially when I have many files in my project and need to find a specific one.

VS Code info:

```
Version: 1.85.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: c6b48c364dde70c12bf977f1da50acda0fd801e3
Date: 2023-11-30T05:35:40.559Z
Electron: 25.9.6
ElectronBuildId: 25427645
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it could be a case of the problem in [ALT + TAB causes Explorer tree view to fully collapse in multi root workspace #139462](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139462). The issue ticket is still open, but there's a linked issue ticket with [a suggested workaround in the comments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136258#issuecomment-1059585471) that you could try in the meantime: put `"skipRefreshExplorerOnWindowFocus": true,` in your user [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

Otherwise, it could be a bug or a regression of a historical issue like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136258, in which case you should raise a new issue ticket using the `Help: Raise Issue` command in the command palette.

For your reference / learning purposes, those issue tickets were found by googling "`github vscode issues explorer collapse OR expand alt+tab`".