# VSCode files become invisible in explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

When renaming a file in vscode insiders build, the entry becomes an empty row. The file is selectable and will show up just fine, but the filename disappears and so does the icon (in this case the TypeScript TS icon).

Another problem I seem to be having is folders losing the ability to expand and show their files. This problem is solved by reloading vscode (Ctrl + shift + p > Reload Window), but it happens randomly and with random folders.

I dont know if it is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581864/vscode-collapses-folder-in-explorer-when-it-gets-focus) I posted on here, which also had to do with my VSCode explorer window. That problem seems to be fixed now after adding a hidden setting to my settings.json file (see [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136258)). Any help would be appreciated!

VSCode build info:

```
Version: 1.85.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: 92772dcc29bd74108ab61ba9da5ad1f5154639ff
Date: 2023-11-30T18:37:45.605Z
Electron: 25.9.6
ElectronBuildId: 25427645
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```